# How to list all loadable kernel modules?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules

I'm looking for a few kernel modules to load `i2c-dev` and `i2c-bcm2708`. But the `modprobe` command returns:

```
sudo modprobe i2c-dev
modprobe: module i2c-dev not found in modules.dep
```

How do I list all the available modules in the system? In which directory are they located?

Comment: The kernel didnt compile this i2c-dev. You didnt find this module.The kernel modules located /lib/modules/'kernel-version'/drivers. When you are looking for linux drivers.

Comment: You can check on /boot/config-'kernel-version' and read this config file.You should know which linux modules are loaded or modulars or during compiling kernel didnt enable i2c-dev module.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

- By default `modprobe` loads modules from kernel subdirectories located in the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)` directory. Usually all files have extension `.ko`, so you can list them with

  ```
  find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko'
  ```

  or, taking into account compressed files:

  ```
  find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*'
  ```
- Each module can be also loaded by referring to its aliases, stored in the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias` (and `modules.alias.bin`).
- However, to load a modules successfully `modprobe` needs their dependencies listed in the file `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.dep` (and a corresponding binary version `modules.dep.bin`). If some module is present on the system, but is not on the list, then you should run a command `depmod` which will generate such dependencies and automatically include your module to `modules.dep` and `modules.dep.bin`.
- Additionally, if the module is successfully loaded it will be listed in the file `/proc/modules` (also accessed via command `lsmod`).

Comment: Redhat 7 modules files are compressed in .xz (not sure if it is because of kernel version or OS version.. if someone can clarify it to me?) so I think you might not find them with jimmij's find command. Use instead  `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name *.ko* `

Comment: @Pozinux Discovered the same thing here on Arch linux at 4.13.10, which have the ending `.gz`

Comment: @posinux: beware : the shell may expand your `*.ko*` if you happen to have in your current dir some file matching it.  better to escape it between single quotes:    `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*'`

Answer (score 13):

Type `modprobe` and press tab, the autocomplete list should contain all the loadable modules

Comment: it doesn't work for some systems

Comment: Requires necessary completion scripts in order to work

Comment: Also its double tab, and you may get prompted that there is a specific large number of entries to list, then press `y` to list them. Also this answer does not provide the second part to OP's question `which directory are they located?`

Comment: takes very long even on newer systems and doesn't give a really good way to look at ll the entries... just paging into one direction of 30k possibilities is probably not very much enlightening

Answer (score 10):

There is `lsmod` command of `kmod` package in [Arch Linux](https://archlinux.org) what lists and shows the status of Linux kernel modules that contains other useful commands such as `modinfo`, `rmmod` `modprobe` too.

To **l**ist all binaries provided by the package you can type:

```
pacman -Ql kmod | grep /bin/ --color=always
```

, and you can also check for the **o**wner package of a binary with `pacman -Qo lsmod`.

---

`Q` switch is to **q**uery locally installed packages (unlike `S` to **s**ynchronize, ie. to check remotely).

Comment: Where it's important to highlight that `lsmod` only shows *already* loaded modules. The Author of this thread had the problem to load a module that wasn't in the map of the loadable kernel modules. Besides, this solution only applies to archlinux. Which might be not the distribution of the Author and might not solve the problem for others.

Comment: @Akendo `lsmod` is also available on Ubuntu, at least. However, I agree this does not solve OP’s problem.

Comment: There is absolutely no point in talking about Arch specifically, and `lsmod` is a universally available command. Furthermore, the whole point of the question is to list **loadable/available** modules, whereas `lsmod` only prints listed modules. This answer should be moderated.

Answer (score 7):

I prefer to use `depmod`. With the command: `depmod -av|grep MOD_NAME`, your system will generate the modules.dep/map files and grep through it.
The `-v` parameter is important for verbosity and `-a` to ensure that all possible modules from `/lib/modules/` are used for the modules.dep file.

This way it's possible to ensure, that a requested kernel module is mapped to the kernel as loadable. When the desire kernel module is not listed in the output, you know that the kernel won't find it.

Comment: According to `man depmod` option `-a` is not needed -- it is enabled by default, if no file names are given in command line.

Comment: I don't see the -v parameter on the version of depmod included in BusyBox that I'm using, but -n may work.

Answer (score 5):

You can check how autocompletion does it:

```
$ complete -p modprobe
complete -F _modprobe modprobe
declare -f _modprobe
_modprobe () 
{ 
...
```

In that function there's an internal `_installed_modules`

```
$ declare -f _installed_modules
_installed_modules () 
{ 
    COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W "$(PATH="$PATH:/sbin" lsmod |
        awk '{if (NR != 1) print $1}')" -- "$1"))
}
```

So `lsmod | awk '{if (NR != 1) print $1}'` should show you the list of modules