# Low resolution in GRUB and tty

Tags: grub2, nvidia, tty, uefi, resolution

After upgrading from Fedora 33 to 34, the resolution in GRUB and ttys is low resolution and the wrong aspect ratio, seemingly 1024x768, instead of the native 1920x1080.

Tried adding `nvidia-drm.modeset=1` in grub’s linux command line, and while that fixes plymouth’s resolution partway into the booting process (after entering the LUKS passphrase), the grub menu, early part of booting, and tty (after booting is completed) are all still stuck with the low resolution.

- motherboard is set to UEFI mode with CSM and fastboot disabled
- system uses LUKS encryption
- proprietary nvidia drivers and akmod installed from negativo17's repo

`sudo hwinfo --framebuffer` produces no output.

`fbset -i` strangely shows only one resolution at 1024x768:

```
# fbset -i

mode "1024x768-76"
    # D: 78.653 MHz, H: 59.949 kHz, V: 75.694 Hz
    geometry 1024 768 1024 768 32
    timings 12714 128 32 16 4 128 4
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : EFI VGA
    Address     : 0xe0000000
    Size        : 3145728
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 0
    YPanStep    : 0
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 4096
    Accelerator : No
```

At grub’s command prompt, the often suggested `vbeinfo` does not work:

```
grub> vbeinfo
error: ../../grub-core/script/function.c:119:can't find command `vbeinfo`.
```

Original `/etc/default/grub` contents which used to provide native resolution in tty with Fedora 33:

```
GRUB_TIMEOUT=5
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR="$(sed 's, release .*$,,g' /etc/system-release)"
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU=true
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rd.lvm.lv=[...]/root rd.luks.uuid=luks-[...] rhgb quiet rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau"
GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"
GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="console"
GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="gfxterm"
GRUB_GFXMODE="1920x1080x32"
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX="keep"
GRUB_ENABLE_BLSCFG=true
```

Any suggestions of what to try to maintain native 1920x1080 resolution in GRUB and ttys?

Comment: `often suggested vbeinfo does not work` ... you probably have to load the nesessary module before using *vbeinfo* ... i do not know which module contains vbeinfo, it has been many moons since i played with grub

Comment: the command could be `videoinfo` instead

Comment: Good point. It seems `vbeinfo` is for grub-pc, and for grub-efi it's `videoinfo`, but that didn't work either. Not sure if there's some module to load for that too. https://askubuntu.com/questions/577486/how-do-i-run-vbeinfo

Comment: Try to load vbeinfo at system boot if your installed OS in UEFI

echo vbeinfo  > /etc/modules-load.d/vbeinfo.conf

Comment: @AhmedMonem The module does not seem to be present: `systemd-modules-load: Failed to find module 'videoinfo'`

Comment: Also, `find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -type f -name '*.ko*'` as suggested in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/184877/how-to-list-all-loadable-kernel-modules does not list `videoinfo` or `vbeinfo` among the loadable kernel modules.

Comment: @adatum Can you please tell us how you blacklisted Nvidia drivers ? It seems that you have not blacklisted it well

Comment: @AhmedMonem Of course the Nvidia drivers are not blacklisted, since that is what is being used on this machine. nouveau is blacklisted with `rd.driver.blacklist=nouveau` as seen above in the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX` line in `/etc/default/grub`.

Answer (score 1):

vbeinfo is a module in grub-pc, not in grub-efi

For grub-efi You've to use **`videoinfo`** instead of vbeinfo

Or You can do the following

```
vim /etc/default/grub

GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"
```

Then

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/fedora/grub.cfg
```

Or [starting with Fedora 34, for both EFI and non-EFI use](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/UnifyGrubConfig):

```
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

And Reboot

Comment: I have tried also tried with `GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="console"` in `/etc/default/grub` and it did not succeed to set the display to native resolution, whether in grub or the ttys.

Comment: @adatum and after editing the grub, have you regenerated the grub configuration file ?

Comment: Yes, with `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` and `dracut -f`

Answer (score 0):

The problem has vanished upon upgrading to Fedora 35. TTY and GRUB are displayed in the native resolution once again.

I did not change grub or nvidia configurations. I'm not sure if a bug was fixed in Fedora or the nvidia drivers. Currently on nvidia driver 495.44.

`fbset -i` now shows the correct native resolution of the display:

```
# fbset -i

mode "1920x1080-77"
    # D: 207.383 MHz, H: 85.273 kHz, V: 77.240 Hz
    geometry 1920 1080 1920 1080 32
    timings 4822 240 32 16 4 240 4
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode

Frame buffer device information:
    Name        : EFI VGA
    Address     : 0xe0000000
    Size        : 8847360
    Type        : PACKED PIXELS
    Visual      : TRUECOLOR
    XPanStep    : 0
    YPanStep    : 0
    YWrapStep   : 0
    LineLength  : 8192
    Accelerator : No
```